# .htaccess password protect after log in not showing css or images

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I am trying to password protect my PrestaShop site and I created the .htaccess and .htpasswd files when I upload them to the root directory and the /dev folder respectively everything seems to work, until I enter the username and password, at which point the page reloads and displays the website with NO CSS or images. Please someone HELP!

I am unable to keep the files up as it is conflicting with the client QA-ing, but I need to protect the site quickly to hide it from some disgruntled workers.

I greatly appreciate all replies!!! Please just ask if more info is required

Comment: I would recommend atleast posting the htaccess, you basicly gave us almost no information. Besides that, are there any error logs? Did you try developer mode to see what it says about the files which should have been loaded?

Comment: heres the .htaccess
    `AuthUserFile /dev/.htpasswd`
    `AuthGroupFile /dev/null`
    `AuthName "Restricted Access"`
    `AuthType Basic`
    `<Limit GET>`
    `require user atop`
    `</Limit>`

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to upload .htaccess and .htpasswd to the root dir. I'm not sure why you're adding it to your /dev directory as well.

Your .htaccess should look something like this:

```
AuthUserFile /webhost/path/root/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Files"
Require valid-user
```

More info: http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

Comment: heres the .htaccess
    `AuthUserFile /dev/.htpasswd`
    `AuthGroupFile /dev/null`
    `AuthName "Restricted Access"`
    `AuthType Basic`
    `<Limit GET>`
    `require user atop`
    `</Limit>`